# Should I have to follow some extra steps to modify httpd.conf file?

Tags: apache, file, httpd.conf

I have a dedicated server. Are there some special steps which I have to follow while editing httpd.conf file? I try to revert back the changes but problem is still same.

Comment: Please provide specific details of what you try and what your problems are. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Actually previously my client getting error in adding an domain"How to Fix cPanel Error: Sorry, that domain is already set up (remove it from httpd.conf?)", so i remove the code related to that domain from httpd.conf file. but now i am not able to terminate any account easily.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is get solved. Actually the problem is that i have changed the WHM password and that's why it does not connect to my WHMCS and my IP get blocked in firewall. That is the reason i was not able to terminate any account through WHMCS panel. If anyone get the same problem then they first have to check Firewall for IP blocking.